Confusion regarding Wasserstein-1 distance between a probabilty measure and its push-forward
The Wasserstein-1 metric between two probability measures is defined as
$$W_1(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_Y) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_Y)} \mathbb{E}_{(X,Y) \sim \gamma } \Vert X-Y \Vert  $$
where $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_Y)$ is the set of all couplings between $\mathbb{P}_X$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y$. Suppose $f$ is a measurable function, and I am measuring the distance between the distribution of a random variable $X$ and $f(X)$ using the metric, is the below correct?
$$W_1(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_{f}) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_f)} \mathbb{E}_{(X,f) \sim \gamma } \Vert X-f \Vert  = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}_{X}, \mathbb{P}_{X})} \mathbb{E}_{(X_1,X_2) \sim \gamma } \Vert X_1-f(X_2) \Vert$$
If the above is correct, it is not necessary that we have $X_1=X_2$ a.s. for any $(X_1, X_2) \sim \gamma$. That is, it is not necessarily the case that:
$$W_1(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_{f(X)}) = \mathbb{E}\Vert X - f(X)\Vert$$
However, from time to time, I do find someone using the above equality, which is quite confusing. My understanding is that the two "$X$" (i.e., $X_1$ and $X_2$) in a coupling $\gamma$ in  $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_X, \mathbb{P}_X)$ can be dependent in different ways as long as their marginal distrbutions are $\mathbb{P}_X$. Is this correct?
